# How to package and install Windows 10 application on other computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have developed a `Universal Windows Application` (Windows 10). I am now to the point where I would like to package it up and deploy it to an image of Windows 10 or have it on a shared drive and have users double click an .exe and install it.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. Does anyone have any experience doing this? If so, could you provide any type of suggestions on how I can accomplish this too?

Comment: There is no "EXE" for a UWP application. You're trying to sideload, which is documented on technet for example: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269549(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And, if you're really looking for a traditional EXE model, you may not want to use UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read this tutorial: [How Do I Deploy a Windows 8 App to Another Device for Testing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx)

For Windows 10 need setup Developer Mode is Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at **Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer (WICD)** (contained in [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx)). With WICD you are able to create a provisioning package containing appx packages. Afterwards, distribute the provisioning package to your users/pcs.

[image: Adding appx packages in WICD]

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.